# Letting my Windows 8 PC turn screen and speakers on/off

Tags: windows, windows-8, display, speakers, peripherals

I use Windows 8 Pro, 64 bits. My computer is a desktop one, with both screen and speakers as separate pieces.

A few months ago, I was in awe when I discovered that you can make it so that the computer will automatically turn the printer on when it needs to print, and then turn it back off when it's done. Awesome. No more "What's happening? Is it broken? Why is nothing happening? Oh, right, it's turned off."

I'm wondering if there's a way to do the same with the screen and speakers, to make them automatically turn on when the computer is turned on, and off when it's shut down. It would be really practical. No more turning the PC on and then going off somewhere, thinking I would hear it if I was going to be needed, and then being sad because I didn't hear Skype/MSN messages, having forgotten to turn the speakers on.

Comment: You printer is most likely not "Off" but in a sleep mode (so it can detect the signal to wake up).  Monitors also so this as well (go into sleep mode).  speakers, not so much (not that I've seen).  So what is you actual question?  Waht have you tried already?  Why isn't the standard display sleep functionality built into widows (and most OS's) enough?

Comment: Well, it's never a good idea to leave the screen on all the time even when the computer is turned off. Same for the speakers. Besides, I sleep quite close to the computer, and the LEDs would be disturbing. Mostly, it's just that I'd like it if there were something comfortable enough to allow me not to need to think of turning the speakers on, for example. Not like it was so important to begin with. :p

Comment: @techie007 , would you post your comment as an answer? After a while like this, if no one has solution, then I'll be marking your answer as the right one, as in, nope, there's no way. Thing is, I can't because it's a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You printer is most likely not "Off" but in a sleep mode (so it can detect the signal to wake up). Monitors also so this as well (go into sleep mode). speakers, not so much (not that I've seen).